# Feasibility - When is a set defined by linear inequalities empty (in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $n \geq 4$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming, geometric-inequalities

Consider the set $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, defined by the following
$m > n \geq 4 $ **linear** inequalities:

$$\begin{cases}
a_{1,1}x_1 + a_{1,2}x_2 + \ldots + a_{1,n} x_n \leq b_1\\
~\vdots \\
a_{m,1}x_1 + a_{m,2}x_2 + \ldots + a_{m,n} x_n \leq b_m,
\end{cases}
$$

where $a_{i,j}$ and $b_i$ are integer (i.e. $\in \mathbb{Z}$) constants, and $x_j$ are unknown variables.

As a side remark, $a_{i,j}$ can be represented as a $m$-by-$n$ matrix $A$, $b_{i}$ can be represented by a $m$-by-$1$ vector and $x_j$ can be represented by a $n$-by-$1$ vector.

Is it possible to establish in an algebraic way if the set $\mathcal{S}$ is empty? In other words, are there properties that $A$ and $b$ must fulfill in order $\mathcal{S} = \emptyset$?

It is easy to answer to this question when $n = 2$ or $n=3$ by using geometrical arguments. But what can we do for $n \geq 4$?

Comment: There is no easy algebraic condition such as by performing a few operations on $A,b$ that would yield the answer. You can use a variant of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma but it is not like the other alternative in the lemma is "easier". Ultimately you are asking about deciding the feasibility of a general linear problem and the only way to answer is to solve that problem.